# Catching last datetime after update wont result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
UPDATE sm 
SET  sm_fecha_venc = (SELECT MIN(nd_fecha_venc) FROM [db_facturacion].[dbo].[tb_notas_debito] 
                            WHERE sm_codigo = nd_num_servicio
                            -- AND nd_referencia = sm_cod_producto
                                AND nd_num_factura = sm_cod_factura 
                                AND nd_estado = 'G')
    ,sm_fecha_ult_pago = (SELECT MAX(nd_fecha_pago) FROM [db_facturacion].[dbo].[tb_notas_debito] 
                            WHERE sm_codigo = nd_num_servicio
                            -- AND nd_referencia = sm_cod_producto
                                AND nd_num_factura = sm_cod_factura 
                                AND nd_estado = 'C')

    ,sm_fecha           = GETDATE()
    ,sm_cod_factura_ren = @i_num_factura

   OUTPUT DELETED.sm_fecha_venc      AS FECHA_VENC_OLD,
          DELETED.sm_fecha_ult_pago  AS FECHA_ULT_PAGO_OLD,
          DELETED.sm_fecha           AS FECHA_OLD,
          DELETED.sm_cod_factura_ren AS COD_FACTURA_REN_OLD
    INTO @TABLATABLA --
FROM [db_facturacion].[dbo].[tb_servicios] sm --WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN #servicios AS T  ON sm_codigo = num_servicio
WHERE sm_tipo_bien_protegido = 1
AND [sm_estado] = 1
--AND sm.sm_cod_forma_contrato = 1
AND sm.sm_tipo_inventario = tipo_inventario


 /*===========================
       INSERTED DELETED
 =============================*/

UPDATE db_facturacion.[dbo].[tb_log_cambio_servicio]
SET         cs_fecha_venc_old        = FECHA_VENC_OLD
           ,cs_fecha_ult_pago_old    = FECHA_ULT_PAGO_OLD                                              
           ,cs_fecha_old             = FECHA_OLD
           ,cs_cod_factura_ren_old   = COD_FACTURA_REN_OLD
FROM @TABLATABLA        
WHERE cs_codigo = @ID_ULTIMO_ING  (LAST @@IDENTITY)
```

Im trying to save the last dates into a log table, just in case I have to return those dates back.

The code works good, just that it's catching the actual date and inserted in the log table.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you really using [`@@IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?